# How to distribute VC redist with an MSI when using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-2015

We are just switching to Visual Studio 2015, but we have found a problem in deployment of our application.

We use Wix/MSI for deployment and until now we were using merge modules for distribution of VC redist.

But now we have a problem that our application requires **ucrtbase.dll**. There is a new **Universal CRT** according to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx) and it is not contained in any merge module.

In above-mentioned article they are saying that:

> There will not be a merge module for the Universal CRT. If you currently use the CRT merge modules and still want to deploy the Visual C++ libraries centrally, we recommend that you move to the above mentioned Windows Update package or to the VCRedist. Alternatively, you may choose to link statically to the Universal CRT and the Visual C++ libraries

Does this mean that we cannot distribute C++ runtime with our MSI as it cannot run executables (VCRedist.exe)? Or is there a way to compile our project in **Visual Studio 2015** so it will not require this Universal CRT?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use WiX, you could switch to Burn and run the VC Redist packages as part of the setup.

The article you referenced also says that app-local deployment of the Dlls is supported, so you could install the appropriate Dlls without needing redist.

I would use Burn to install the official redist - it's the only way that Mocrosoft can service those Dlls if there are issues. If you use app-local or your own copies of the Dlls you may need to ship patches or upgrades if there are security issues in those Dlls.